# Finding the min and max date from a timeseries range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe laid out like the following with site names and a range of dates for each site.

```
Site       Date
Site_1     02/09/2011
Site_1     03/09/2011
Site_1     04/09/2011
Site_1     05/09/2011
Site_2     14/01/2010
Site_2     15/01/2010
Site_2     16/01/2010
Site_2     17/01/2010
```

I'd like to find the start and end dates for each site and lay the dataframe out like this:

```
Site       Start_Date     End_Date
Site_1     02/09/2011     04/09/2011
Site_2     14/01/2010     17/01/2010
```

I know I can find the min and max of the full range like this:

```
df['Date'].max()
df['Date'].min()
```

Just not sure what the best method is to apply this separately to each site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Max and Min date in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024797/max-and-min-date-in-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise using a `groupby` on the "site" column and aggregating each group into a `min` and `max` date.

```
df.groupby("Site").agg({'date': ['min', 'max']})
```

This will return the `min` and `max` date for each site.

I haven't tried out the code, but it should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using the advanced syntax of `groupby`+`agg` you can directly get your custom format:

```
df.groupby('Site')['Date'].agg([('Start_Date', 'min'), ('End_Date', 'max')])
```

output:

```
        Start_Date    End_Date
Site                          
Site_1  02/09/2011  05/09/2011
Site_2  14/01/2010  17/01/2010
```

Comment: what if the observations are like: site_1 then site_2 then site_1 again. So the results are multiple intervals of start and end date for each site?

Comment: @Hakim then use `df.groupby(df['Site'].ne(df['Site'].shift()).cumsum())` as grouper.

Comment: thanks, I can see the intervals but with only numbers (1 to 8 or something) so lost the site column.